# Volatile Variables in Arduino ISR

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I have a simple program and I'm declaring the variable that is passed between the normal loop and ISR as volatile but I'm still getting garbage when displaying the value of 'count'.....I'm assuming I'm missing some small detail.  Any help is appreciated and I'm sure it's something small.  Thank you in advance!

```
const int Int_Pin = 3;                // the interrupt pin location
volatile int Count = 0;               // how many times the int pin pressed

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(Int_Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Int_Pin), Int_Routine, LOW);      // indicates an interrupt routine is used
                                                                          // trigger on Int_Pin based on a LOW signal

  Serial.begin(9600);                                                     // baud rate for Serial Comm
}

void loop() 
{    
   Serial.println("From the top...");

   for (int a = 1; a < 11; a++)                                           //      counter from 1 to 10 then     print the count value
  {

Serial.println(a);
delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println(Count);
}

void Int_Routine() 
{
  Count = Count + 1;
}
```

Comment: Please describe the "garbage" you're getting - is this a numeric value that you weren't expecting, or something that's not a number at all?

Comment: this is a numeric value that is something like 2057 or 16914 when I'm expecting to see an incremental change of 1 or 2 starting from 0.

Comment: Ok, what's the actual source of the interrupt?  If it's something mechanical, like a pushbutton, then it's going to "bounce" (unless there's an external debounce circuit) - and your interrupt handler is fast enough to see each bounce as a separate event.  Thousands of bounces per press seems unlikely, though, so there may be something else wrong here.

Comment: I agree and since sometimes the value come back as negative, I think it has something to do how the value is pulled from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see incremental changes like 0, 1, 2, 3 when you're using LOW as the trigger.  LOW lets the interrupt run over and over and over again as long as the pin stays LOW.  If you want one count per pulse then use RISING or FALLING. Understand that even then you may still see multiples for each press if this is something like a button or a switch where you have some terminal bounce.